# Degree of a differential equation doubt

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What should be the degree of this differential equation 1 or 2 
$$\frac{d^2x}{dy^2}+\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^3}=0$$

As per definition: 
the degree of a differential equation is the power of highest differential coefficient, which appearing in the given equation, when the differential coefficients are free from radicals and fractions. 
So I think I should remove the radical in the equation above and the degree will be 2.
Is it correct ?

Comment: You might want to edit.  I'm not seeing "the equation above".

Comment: Its given in the image

Comment: If you mean the order, it's a second order differential equation.

Comment: Degree is different to Order as he defined in the question.

Comment: I think that you mean it's order.


Its ODE classification:

It is a second- order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Comment: I would say the order is $1$, since the highest differential coefficient is the second derivative, which is to the power $1$. But I am not sure it is the correct interpretation of the definition.

Comment: "the power of highest differential coefficient": sorry but this is meaningless.

Comment: I think the OP has mixed up anything. Like stated by the op the answer to the highest power of the highest order derivative is 1. But if you square the equation it becomes 2, if you take it to the 3rd power it becomes 3, and so forth. If you are forbidden to change the expression, only then you will have an unique answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find degree of a differential equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436288/how-to-find-degree-of-a-differential-equation)

Answer (score 3):

A better definition is *the power of the highest order derivative*, when the equation is *polynomial in the derivatives*.

Hence

$$\left(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right)^2=1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^3$$

is of the second order and second degree.

Answer (score 1):

According the definition in the question the degree must be 2. Some textbooks use the term "coefficient differentials" meaning "derivative". In my view, kind of definition given in another answer by Yves Daoust is more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

As per definition: the degree of a differential equation is the power of highest differential coefficient, which appearing in the given equation, when the differential coefficients are free from radicals and fractions. So I think I should remove the radical in the equation above and the degree will be 2.