# What is the degree of $(y')^{-2}+5y'=0 $?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In the video(time stamp present) https://youtu.be/L61hIm_WoC8?t=2944   ,

the differential equation  $(y')^{-2}+5y'=0$ is said to have no degree referring that it is not polynomial in derivative(y'), *"The teacher says that the equation is not polynomial in derivative so the degree can't be calculated and puts a cross on the right side of the equation."*

but I guess multiplying the equation with $(y')^2$, it becomes $1+5(y')^3=0$ which is polynomial in derivative(y'), it has degree 3.

So, which one is correct?

Comment: I would say the degree is three. Sorry I don't know the language of your video.

Comment: The teacher just says that the equation is not polynomial in derivative so that the degree can't be calculated and puts a cross mark on the right side of the equation.

Comment: @Isham here you are again helping me by correcting formats. Thanks, Pal!

Comment: I don't agree with your teacher. Yes the equation is not in polynomial in derivatives but you can make it polynomial in derivatives by multiplication. So the degree should be defined.

Comment: Yw Nature...you get more answers and comments if it's well formatted

Comment: The fact that the equation involves the first derivative of $y$ would for me make it a first degree ordinary differential equaltion, though possibly a nonlinear one.  As you point out, a slight algebraic manipulation (assuming $y$ is a real function) makes the DE quite trivial, $y' = constant$.  However such a thing is still a first degree *differential equation* by conventional terminology.

Comment: @hardmath Aren't you confusing between degree and order of ODE ?

Comment: @hardmath so what's the verdict?

Comment: @user45914123:  Maybe I should be making such a distinction.  Degree can be applied to polynomials, and perhaps that is what the assigned exercise was about.  I assumed "degree" here meant the order of derivative in the differential equation.  I'm not a fan of posting questions here in the vein of "my teacher marked my answer wrong and I don't see why".   Hence I offered a Comment rather than an Answer in this case.

Comment: @Nature I checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_differential_equation) and an old question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436288/how-to-find-degree-of-a-differential-equation?rq=1. From what I see the degree should be $3$.

Comment: @user45914123  I got my answer. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @user45914123 But if one rewrites the equation once again as $y'=(-1/5)^{1/3}$ then the degree becomes one. So is it *three* or *one*?

Comment: @A.Γ. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1588617/51633. The degree is one; take $x = 5$ what is the degree of this polynomial $1$ or $3 (x^3 = 125)$ ?

Comment: @user45914123 Right, so the answer is that $(y')^{-2}+5y'=0$ has no degree.

Comment: @A.Γ. I see what you are getting into, but I would say that the degree is $3$; check the definition of degree of ODE : In mathematics, the degree of a differential equation is the power of its highest derivative, after the equation has been made rational and integral in all of its derivatives.

Comment: @user45914123 The problem is that if we allow transformations then for a correct definition it is necessary to ensure that all such transformations lead to the same degree. Here is my trouble, because the above equation can be transformed into a degree three as well as a degree one equivalent equation.

Comment: @A.Γ. I get your point but then degree will not be defined for any equation. 
Take $y' = 4$ and $y'^2 = 16$. What will be degree ?

Comment: @user45914123 Here is my point: if in the equation LHS=0 (differential or algebraic) the LHS is polynomial (in derivatives if it is DE), we may define the degree of the equation = the degree of LHS. Equivalent equations may have different degrees. If LHS is not polynomial, then degree is undefined.

Comment: @Nature I do not see it is different. It says "When an equation is polynomial in all the differential coefficients involved, the power to which the highest differential coefficient is raised is known as the degree of the equation." (c) **When it is polynomial** is important assumption, meaning that if it is not polynomial, the degree is undefined. However, the equation can possibly be rewritten to become polynomial, then *this new equation* has a degree (as in the example in your link).

Comment: @A.Γ. Exactly, the equation before was not polynomial since it contains  e^y′=x+x^3+x^5+y, upon some manipulations the equation becomes polynomial and thus can have a degree.

Comment: @Gio67   https://math.stackexchange.com/users/355873/gio67 please shed some light on this

Answer (score 3):

The degree of a differential equation is an artificial concept which is of no use.  The order of a differential equation with the linearity or non-linearity are essential.

The given differential  equation $$   (y')^{-2}+5y'=0$$ is a first order equation which is equivalent to $$1+5(y')^3=0$$

This equation is in term equivalent to $$ y'= \sqrt[3] {(-1/5)} $$ which is a first order linear equation.

As you notice the concept of degree is not essential at all and does not play any role in solving the equation.

Comment: "The degree of a differential equation is an artificial concept which is of no use. The order of a differential equation with the linearity or non-linearity are essential." I can't write that in tests. While degree has been mentioned in the text, I am supposed to understand the concept. So, please help me understanding it rather than making me feel to skip it.

Comment: "As you notice the concept of degree is not essential at all and does not play any role in solving the equation." That is true for order of ODE also.

Comment: @user45914123 The order plays a significant role. For example a second order linear homogeneous  equation has two linearly independent solutions while a higher order  linear homogeneous equation has more linearly  independent solutions.

Comment: @Nature What I am trying to say is that you can change the degree of your equation by algebraic manipulations without changing the solutions, therefore the degree is not a well-defined concept. You can answer the question by saying the degree is  $3$ in the present form of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

From the links provided by the @user45914123, it can be concluded that the degree for the given differential equation is 3.

Comment: What is the purpose of this?