# Degree of differential equation $\sqrt{1+\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}=x+\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, absolute-value

> Degree of the differential equation $\sqrt{1+\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}=x+\frac{dy}{dx}$

Degree of the differential equation $\sqrt{1+\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}=x+\frac{dy}{dx}$ is said to be "not defined" in my reference.

**Doubt 1**

What if I do:
$$
\color{blue}{\sqrt{1+\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}=x+\frac{dy}{dx}}\implies 1+\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\bigg[x+\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg]^2
$$
Now can I say the degree is $1$. If not, is it because squaring both sides add more information into the equation that both the differential equations are not exactly the same ?

**Doubt 2**

Thanx @farruhota for the link: [How to find degree of a differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436288/how-to-find-degree-of-a-differential-equation) or check page 4 of [ordinary differential equations by E. L. Ince](https://ia800307.us.archive.org/28/items/ordinarydifferen029666mbp/ordinarydifferen029666mbp.pdf)

If I'm allowed to square both sides and say that the degree is $1$, as in the link, can I also square again and say the degree is $2$ right ?

Comment: Could you tell us what your definition of *degree* of an ODE is, please?

Comment: @user539887 degree is the highest power of the highest order derivative, but it is only defined iff the diff. eqn. is a polynomial equation in its derivatives, ie. $y', y'', y''', y''''$. etc.

Comment: Your original equation is not polynomial, so the degree is undefined. When you square both sides you will get a polynomial equation $y''=(y')^2+2xy'+x^2-1$, of degree $\color{red}2$. But notice that this will not be the same ODE (for instance, the initial conditions $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=-1$ are in the domain of the squared ODE whereas they are not in the domain of the original one).

Comment: @user539887 btw squaring gives a polynomial of degree $1$ i think. Ok so squaring changes the original differential equation right, so both not the same. But, wht if the equation is the second one $\pm\sqrt{1+\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}}=x+\dfrac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: in the second case the degree is 1 right ?

Comment: $(y')^2+2xy'+x^2-1$ has degree two in $y'$. In the second case, again this is not a polynomial equation (indeed, this is two equations!), so the degree is still undefined.

Comment: it is $y''$ not $y'$

Comment: The squared equation is $$y''(x)=(y'(x))^2+2xy'(x)+x^2-1,$$ and this is a polynomial of degree two in $y'(x)$.

Comment: @user539887 degree is the highest power of the highest order derivative

Comment: For equations of what type?

Comment: for differential equations this s the definition of "degree".https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_differential_equation

Comment: see related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436288/how-to-find-degree-of-a-differential-equation

Comment: This is my last comment. The definition of order as given in the linked article makes sense for equations of the type $y^{(k)}=a_l(x,y,\ldots,y^{(k-2)})(y^{(k-1)})^l+\ldots+a_0(x,y,\ldots,y^{(k-2)})$ (then, if $a_l\not\equiv0$, the degree is $l$). But if we define the degree as you seem to understand it, then for $y^{(k)}=f(x,y,\ldots,y^{(k-1)})$ the degree is always one, whatever you take for $f$. And now the concept has no content whatsoever.

Comment: You just answered your own question. If the equation was $1+y'' = (x + y')^2$ then the degree is indeed $1$. I'm not sure if this information is very useful, though. It's obscure enough that a lot people are confused.

Comment: @Dylan So u mean the concept of degree of a differential equation is not well defined ?. Can i say the degree is undefined if the equation is $\sqrt{1+y''}=x+y'$ ?. But i think the following link says the opposite in a similar problem :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436288/how-to-find-degree-of-a-differential-equation

Comment: No, the concept is fine. I just think it's not very *useful* or *relevant*. When would you ever need to know it? Are there specific methods tailored to different degrees, like with the order?

Comment: @Dylan I do agree. but why do we mention it then, don't understand.

Comment: Well, we don't. I almost never see it in anything regarding ODEs, aside from a couple of questions on here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find degree of a differential equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436288/how-to-find-degree-of-a-differential-equation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is the greatest $n$ for which an $n$th derivative is present, while the degree is the highest power of such maximal-order derivatives, after the equation is written in rational form with all exponents integers. The equation $1+y''=x^2+2xy'+y'^2$ has order $2$, degree $1$.

Comment: ok. wht abt the degree of the differential equation $\sqrt{1+y''}=x+y'$ ?. Is it undefined ? or is it as  defined by E. L. Ince, degree $1$ when rationalised by squaring both members ?

Comment: @ss1729 Ince is right.

Comment: if squaring is ok, what if I square again and say the degree is 2 ?

Comment: @ss1729 The point is to obtain the minimum integer exponents through rationalisation, rather like computing the algebraic degree of an algebraic number. Similarly, don't try differentiating to increase the degree.